# how can I display this tab content based on an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

for the tab component [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is there a way that I can display or show the tab contents or let us say open the tab .. where  that is based on an event or using $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to set the active tab for Angular Boostrap UI like so:

```
$scope.tabs[0].active = true;
```

where $scope.tabs is:

```
$scope.tabs = [
  { title:'Dynamic Title 1', content:'Dynamic content 1' },
  { title:'Dynamic Title 2', content:'Dynamic content 2', disabled: true }
];
```

Comment: this sets the tab title to be active only. This does not display the tab content when another tab's content is displayed.

Comment: Maybe Im not understanding your question but is this not what your trying to do http://plnkr.co/edit/KzyySmFY3Tb7Pw7tr3hc?p=preview   Maybe your own plnkr would help figure this out